# Email successfully sent and i received the mail but the status of button and form has no change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

this is my first time to ask here, i hope i can find a solution regarding my problem. (Note: i am not a good in ajax  but i can understand as much as i can .. just  have more research.

below is my problem:
 my Email  successfully sent and i received the mail but the status of button and form has no change.. the caption of submit button did not back to normal and just like no happened at a`enter code here`ll..  just  says.. Sending... (the caption of button after submit the form) 
FYI: i'll just modified this code from different source in order to work in my form..  i add captcha on  it which is not include from the email codes. below is the  whole codes.

**| the html form**

```html
<h3>
    <font color="#2E86C1">Contact form.</font>
</h3>

<div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
    <h3>Posted your message successfully!</h3>
</div>

<div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
    <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form.
</div>

<form class="customform" role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
    <div class="s-12">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" title="Your name" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div class="s-12">
        <input name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" title="Your e-mail" type="email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="s-12">
        <input name="phone" placeholder="Your phone" title="Your phone" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div class="s-12">
        <input name="subject" placeholder="Subject" title="Your subject" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div class="s-12">
        <textarea placeholder="Your message" name="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <!--<form method="GET"> -->
    <img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" />

    <!-- CHANGE TEXT LINK -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="
        document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
        document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();" id="change-image"><br>
        Not readable? Change text.
    </a><br />

    <input type="text" required style="height: 40px; width: 200px; font-size: 18px;" placeholder="Enter codes here" name="captcha" id="captcha" autocomplete="off"><br />

    <div class="s-12 m-12 l-4"><button class="color-btn" type="submit">Submit Button</button></div>
</form>
```

**|the php mail code:**

```php
<?php session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $mail_to = "myemail@domain.com";

    # Sender Data `enter code here`
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $name    = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array(" ", " "), strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
    $email   = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone   = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $captcha = trim($_POST["captcha"]);

    if (empty($name) or !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) or empty($phone) or empty($subject) or empty($message)) {

        # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($captcha)) != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
        //$hasError = true;

        //  http_response_code(400);
        echo "Captcha code not match try again.";
        exit;
    } else {
        $captcha = trim($_POST['captcha']);
        exit;
    }

    # Mail Content
    $content = "Name: $name\n";
    $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
    $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    # email headers.
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    # Send the email.
    $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
    if ($success) {
        # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong, we couldn't send your message.";
    }
} else {
    # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

**| the js code:**

```js
$(function () {
    function after_form_submitted(data) {
        if (data.result == 'success') {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, val) {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function () {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if (label) {
                    $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
                }
            });

        }//else
    }

    $('#reused_form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function () {
            $btn.prop('type', 'button');
            $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'mail.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: after_form_submitted,
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    });
});
```

i hope you can help me to fix the code .. since i am not an expert .. but eager to learn

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have no error checking in your Ajax request, so if there’s anything going wrong, you’ll never know. Double check the response from the PHP script by itself, then inspect the response you’re getting from your JS script.

Comment: yeah.. the ajax  works fine..the problem.. that it wont  give me a message if it was sent or failed.   if i type the wrong captcha. the mail will not deliver.. otherwise it is delivered. but no  messsage at all.

Comment: Uh, isn't that the whole point of the captcha? It sounds like you have a problem with your captcha code, not the email side of things.

Comment: C'mon, at least format your code a bit so it is readable ... :-)

Comment: the captcha works fine.. if  captcha is invalid... it wont send the mail  but if its valid mail sent successfull  .. but without any message that if fail or not.